# Is the parent key also downloaded when you observe that key?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code example:

```
database.child("\(Id)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { ss...
```

If we want to download the children under the "Id", is this "Id" key also downloaded? I want to minimise how long id's are incase they are also downloaded.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database? It'll be easier to clarify that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database structure looks like:

```
parentNode
  |-thatId
    |-..children
```

Your query will fetch all the children inside of `thatId` node. You could use orderBy and limit to limit the returned data but again it depends on the context of what it is. Do note that it will also fetch all the nested data within those children. If you need shallow queries then you might have to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-shallow).

Comment: Can those shallow queries used within my swift code? I read just now about it and it seems that this is just HTTPS requests?

Comment: @MedoAlmouhtadi you can't use it within the iOS SDK. Only the REST API has it.